# modify particular list item

Tags: android, android-listview

i want to edit the particular list item after the,all data loaded into listview using base adapter.

we can achieve this by reloading the listview with edited value,but i want to do this without reloading the entire listview data.bcoz the data is huge

Answer (score 0):

If I understand ur question properly, When the list item is clicked, u need to make it editable.

Keep two views, one for editing ( EditText ) another TextView for showing.
On Click of list item or TextViw, make TextView Gone and make EditText visible.
When the editing done ( may be other list item click or Done button of keyboard ) copy the content of EditText to TextView and make EditText Gone and TextView visible.

I have done the same for some of the requirement I had in my pet project